# How to integrate multiple statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run this statement for 20 input boxes. Is there a clean way to combine? Seems like there will be a lot of statements. Designed to capture the data entered into inputs then display them into the HTML once the button is clicked. At the moment just 1 line of code works, need to add it for several.

```js
$(".showreg").click(function(){

  var pagetitle = $('#f_k_page_title').val();  

  if(!pagetitle)
  {pagetitle = "Oop's No value entered";}
  $('#theValue').html(pagetitle);
 });

$(".showreg").click(function(){
  var nametitle = $('#f_name_title').val();

  if(!nametitle)
  {nametitle = "Oop's No value entered";}
  $('#theValue2').html(nametitle);

});
```

HTML

```html
   <span id="theValue"></span>
   <span class="txt_111 s17" id="theValue2">Title:</span>
   <span class="txt_555 s17" id="theValue3"></span>

<div class="btn blue next-btn r-btn regclick3 capture_button showreg mt10">Next</div>
```

FormHTML

```html
<form>
    <input id="f_k_page_title"/>
    <input id="f_name_title"/>

    <input class="btn blue createacc-btn " type="submit" name="submit" value="Create account"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure? You can probably delegate the events, but we'll need to remove the hard references to `id` selectors and use DOM traversal methods instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up the event handler on all the objects that need validation (CSS classes help here):

```js
$(".validateForEmpty").on("blur", function(evt){

 var input = $(this);

 // Get index number of the input within its group.
 var idx = $(".validateForEmpty").index(input);
 
 // Get reference to span corresponding to that same index
 var span = $(".output").get(idx);

 // Validate element that just lost the focus
 if(input.val().trim() === ""){
    $(span).text(input.attr("name") + " Can't be empty!");  // Put message corresponding span
 } else {
    $(span).text(input.attr("name") + " contains: " + input.val());  // Put value in corresponding span  
 }
});
```

```css
.output { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="a" class="validateForEmpty">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="b" class="validateForEmpty"><span class="error"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="c" class="validateForEmpty"><span class="error"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="d" class="validateForEmpty"><span class="error"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="e" class="validateForEmpty"><span class="error"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="f" class="validateForEmpty"><span class="error"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="g" class="validateForEmpty"><span class="error"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="h" class="validateForEmpty"><span class="error"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="i" class="validateForEmpty"><span class="error"></span>
</div>

<div class="outputElements">
  <span class="output"></span>
  <span class="output"></span>
  <span class="output"></span>
  <span class="output"></span>
  <span class="output"></span>
  <span class="output"></span>
  <span class="output"></span>
  <span class="output"></span>
  <span class="output"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that is part of it but require the data entered to be displayed instead of "cant be empty!" if data has been inputted. if not display "cant be empty"

Comment: Thats it, but need to hook it to an id so i can use it else where not directly next to the input box. this is why its starts getting messy

Comment: @Dee Not really, If you have the same amount of `span` elements as you do `input` fields, you can just use the index number of the input (within its group) and pick the correct `span` (within its group) using the index number. That way, you don't need the `span` elements next to the `inputs`.

Comment: @Dee I have updated the answer (again) to show the `span` elements separated from the `input` elements.

Comment: @Dee  You could even give each `input` a `data-output` attribute that has the `id ` of the corresponding `span` as its value. Then, as you validate the `input`, you just have to get its `data-output` value and pre-pend a `#` to it to locate the correct `span` to write to.

Comment: Hi that works great very impressive still learning from help. the on blur function is very useful will certainly use that. the site is data heavy and there is lots of features needed in the ui to address things. Is it easy to adapt this to $(".showreg").click(function(evt){ for when i need to integrate a click

Answer (score 0):

Ideally? Add a common class to all the `input`s you care about, and a `data-valuespan` attribute to each, so we know where to put the message, e.g.

```
<input id="f_k_page_title" class="validatee" data-valuespan="theValue" />
<input id="f_name_title"   class="validatee" data-valuespan="theValue2" />
```

Then:

```
$('.validatee').each( function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var val = el.val() || "Oops, no value entered";

  $('#' + el.data('valuespan')).text( val );
});
```

But if you *really* can't change the HTML, you'll need to trust the order of elements in the form. And account for the fact that all `span`s *except* the first have a number...

```js
$(".showreg").click(function(e) {
  var inps = $('form').first().find('input');

  for (var i = 0; i < inps.length; ++i) {
    var inp = inps[i];

    if (inp.type !== "submit") {
      var spanNum = (i > 0) ? (i + 1) : '';
      var spanName = 'theValue' + spanNum;

      var val = inp.value || 'Oops, no value entered';
      $('#' + spanName).text(val);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span id="theValue"></span>
<span class="txt_111 s17" id="theValue2">Title:</span>
<span class="txt_555 s17" id="theValue3"></span>

<div class="btn blue next-btn r-btn regclick3 capture_button showreg mt10">Next</div>


<form>
  <input id="f_k_page_title" />
  <input id="f_name_title" />
  <input id="f_other" />

  <input class="btn blue createacc-btn " type="submit" name="submit" value="Create account" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks will have a play. The first span can have a number if it helps shorten the code.

Comment: in the first example how would you reference the field else where for data-value-span